# Beautiful soap method soap.find_all doesn't work. Why?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wrote the following code with bs4 and got a weird error. It seems that soup.find_all works until the ad container. Then it throws errors. I think it shouldn't pay attention to the ad container (as it doesn't match the search requirements) and should go further. Instead it throws errors for this li tag and for the next too . All li tags seem to be the same. What might have gone wrong?

```
html_text = requests.get('https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/python;kw?rd=30').text

soup= BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')

print(html_text)

jobs= soup.find_all('li', class_ = 'results__list-container-item')

for job in jobs:

    try:
        pub_day = job.find('span',class_ = "offer-actions__date").text.split()[1]
    except:
        print("except")
        x= datetime.now()
        day = x.strftime("%d")
        pub_day = day
    try:
        pub_month_letters = job.find('span', class_= "offer-actions__date").text.split()[2]
        if 'si' in pub_month_letters:
            pub_month_number = 8
    except:
        print('except')
        x= datetime.now()
        month = x.strftime("%m")
        pub_month_number = month
    pub_date = datetime(2021,int(pub_month_number),int(pub_day))
    now = datetime.now()
    diff = now - pub_date
    try:
        job_title = job.find('h2', class_ = 'offer-details__title').text.replace('  ','')
    except:
        continue
    print(pub_date)
```

[image]

I'll show the output (if I didn't put the try statements, it would stop the execution after the 10th tag):

```
2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00

2021-08-09 00:00:00
2021-08-09 00:00:00
2021-08-09 00:00:00
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
except
```

Comment: try at each except to print smt different, except1 and expet2 so at least you can distinguish what is wong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML data you see on the webpage is rendered with JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it completely. You can use `re`/`json` modules to parse the data from that page:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

html_text = requests.get("https://www.pracuj.pl/praca/python;kw?rd=30").text

data = re.search(r"window\.__INITIAL_STATE__ = ({.*})", html_text).group(1)
data = json.loads(data)

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for offer in data["offers"]:
    print(
        "{:<50} {:<25}".format(
            offer["jobTitle"][:50].strip(), offer["lastPublicated"]
        )
    )
```

Prints:

```
Open Source DevOps Engineer                        2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Scrum Master Platform (Wealth & Personal Banking I 2021-08-09T17:00:00      
RedHat (Senior) DevOps Engineer                    2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Trading Risk Model Development - Specjalista       2021-08-09T17:00:00      
ETL developer / Data engineer                      2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Python developer in Credit Risk Modelling (Special 2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Inżynier devops – Datacenter                       2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Junior Python Developer for Cloud Platform         2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Associate Settings File Engineer                   2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Senior Python/C++ Engineer                         2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Software Engineer                                  2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Senior Python Developer                            2021-08-09T17:00:00      
ETL developer / Data engineer                      2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Quality Assurance - Test Automation Engineer - Hom 2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Senior Python Web Developer                        2021-08-09T17:00:00      
DevOps IT Specialist                               2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Internship – Back-End Intern in Cloud Platform Tea 2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Linux Engineer with German                         2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Traded Risk Quantitative Analyst - Internship      2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Automation Test Engineer                           2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Administrator Rozwiązań Atlassian                  2021-08-09T17:00:00      
Technical Consultant                               2021-08-09T16:52:57.72   
Software Engineer                                  2021-08-09T16:52:31.943  
DevOps Engineer                                    2021-08-09T16:51:00      
Test Engineer                                      2021-08-09T16:35:00      
Security Engineer                                  2021-08-09T16:34:00      
Big Data Senior Developer                          2021-08-09T16:34:00      
Python & JavaScript developer                      2021-08-09T16:32:00      
Senior Python Developer                            2021-08-09T16:30:00      
Senior Software Engineer                           2021-08-09T16:25:00      
Applications Administrator                         2021-08-09T16:20:35.65   
Analityk Systemów IT                               2021-08-09T16:20:00      
Deep Learning Developer in Python                  2021-08-09T16:17:48.297  
Linux & Network Specialist                         2021-08-09T16:16:59.647  
Backend Engineer                                   2021-08-09T16:14:43.287  
Senior Data Engineer (Nifi/Groovy)                 2021-08-09T16:06:00      
Senior Data Engineer (Spark)                       2021-08-09T16:06:00      
Data Scientist                                     2021-08-09T16:06:00      
Full Stack Advanced Analytics Developer            2021-08-09T16:05:00      
Python Development Team Lead                       2021-08-09T15:54:00      
DevOps Engineer                                    2021-08-09T15:50:00      
Software Engineer - IT Associate                   2021-08-09T15:42:55.943  
Junior GCP Data Engineer/Google Academy (zdalnie)  2021-08-09T15:39:00      
AWS Data Engineer                                  2021-08-09T15:37:00      
Marketing and Sales Analytics Analyst / Consultant 2021-08-09T15:37:00      
QA Specialist                                      2021-08-09T15:36:40.697  
Junior AWS Data Engineer (get the AWS skill)       2021-08-09T15:36:00      
Junior AML Validator                               2021-08-09T15:23:00      
Full Stack Web Developer                           2021-08-09T15:22:00      
Junior Developer Integracji Systemów (Mulesoft)    2021-08-09T15:17:00
```

Comment: @Andrey Kesely nice solution! What do you mean by "beautifulsoup doesn't see it completely."? The soup is made out if the ingredients of the request and the rendering part has nothing to do with the parsing. Try ```soup.find_all(text=True)``` as a starting point then apply your json combo at should works as well

Comment: @cards When you do `print(soup)` you will see that only first 10 job offerings are "rendered", the rest is inside `<script>` in JavaScript form.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Great answer! Thank you very much, but I've got a question. Why is the rest inside Java Script? How did you notice it? I dont know almost anything about JS, so i would appreciate just a simple answer

Comment: @Kamila Every webpage is different, so first do `print(soup)` and verify if the tags are really there and `beautifulsoup` can parse it. If not, the data is very probably loaded from elsewhere (from REST API or embedded inside the page in JSON or JavaScript form)

Comment: @Andrey Kesely I got what you mean, thanks for the clarification. So for heavy dynamic pages, such as this one, one should scrap also the javascript part with json, rihgt? This means that inside the page/tags there should be a function which, when triggered transform the dictionary-like stuffs into tags? how to find it? for example href attribute <--> offerUrl key

Comment: @cards Yes, dynamic pages use JavaScript to transform Json to HTML tags. You have to find only source of the data. Good utility is Firefox Developer Tools -> Network tab. Or `Ctrl`+`U` and observe the HTML source code of page.

Comment: @AndrejKesely ah when I looked at ctr + u site it made a lot of sense. Thanks for the whole explanation and the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Some tags returned by `find_all` do not match the search criteria specified in the loop (`job.find('span',class_ = "offer-actions__date")` etc.). In such cases the `find` method returns `None`, and since this value has no `text` attribute an exception is generated.